# Docker compose install requirements in a shared directory

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am having several containers, and each of my containers are having their own Dockerfile. Everytime I am building, using docker-compose `build`, each container runs its own requirements; either from a requirements.txt file `(RUN pip install -r requirements.txt)`, or directly from the Dockerfile `(RUN pip install Django, celery, ...)`. Many of the requirements are common in some of the containers (almost all).

It is working perfectly, but there is a problem with build time. It takes almost 45 minutes to build every container from scratch. (lets say after I deleted all images and containers)

Is there a way, to install all the requirements in a common directory for all containers, so that we dont install the common requirements each time a new container is building?

Docker-compose I am using is version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own base image. Let's say all your containers need django and boto for instance, you can create your own Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3

RUN pip install django boto

# more docker commands
```

Then you can build this image as `arrt_dtu/envbase` and publish it somewhere (dockerhub, internal docker environment of your company). Now you can create your specialized images using this one:

```
FROM arrt_dtu/envbase

RUN pip install ...
```

That's exactly the same principle we have with the ruby image, for instance. The ruby one uses a linux one. If you want a rails image, you can use the ruby one as well. Docker images are totally reusable!